# How to Read a Large Blob from an Oracle Database in Chunks to Avoid Java Heap Space OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, blob

I am working on a Java Spring service that reads a field of type BLOB from an Oracle database. This BLOB field contains a zip file, and my service is supposed to return this file in the response body to the client.

I've implemented the following code:

```
public void datasetDownload(String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IOException {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        String sql = "SELECT CONTENT FROM MY_TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("CONTENT");

                    try (InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                         OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }

                    deleteRecord(id, connection);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call this service, I encounter the following exception:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I suspect that the issue is caused by reading the entire blob from the Oracle database into memory. To resolve this, I guess I need to read the blob in smaller chunks to avoid running out of Java heap space, but i don't know how to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: i tried adding some logs:

```
    public void datasetDownload(String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IOException {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        String sql = "SELECT CONTENT FROM MY_TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    log.info("Start downloading the BLOB");
                    log.info("Total memory available: " + (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / (1024 * 1024)) + " MB");
                    log.info("Max memory available: " + (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / (1024 * 1024)) + " MB");

                    try (InputStream inputStream = resultSet.getBinaryStream("CONTENT");
                         OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

                        int bytesRead;

                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                            log.info("Memory available: " + (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / (1024 * 1024)) + " MB");
                        }
                    }

                    deleteRecord(id, connection);
                    log.info("BLOB download completed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that i can see the last log "BLOB download completed"
and than i get the OutOfMemoryError.

Also, the last memory available log is:
Memory available: 570 MB

Edit: actually i found a solution, i compressed the blob with ZipOutputStream and the machine isn't going OutOfMemory. Still i can't figure out what was the problem

Comment: Which line of the code is causing the error? Is it this one: `Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("CONTENT");` ?

Comment: Hi! i edited my post, im not sure where exactly i get the error, If you can help me debug, I can try.

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace for the `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: I have never used Spring but is the stack trace (of the `OutOfMemoryError`) recorded anywhere? Perhaps in a log file? Also, do all of the `log.info(...` lines, that you added, get executed? The problematic line would be between the last `log.info(...` that got executed and the first one that did not.

Answer (score 0):

In which line does the error occure? with a **resultSet.getBinaryStream()** you could save some lines and it should use less memory, as it does not load the blob first.

Comment: Hi! I tried your solution and seems nothing changed. The memory available from the logs seems to decrease by 200 MB that is the dimension of the file (BLOB).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).